# Why is UICollectionViewDataSource called when UIViewController is dismissed?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, ios10

I have a `UIViewController` containing a `UICollectionView` presented using

> `present(selectFromCollectionView, animated: false, completion: nil)`

When I dismiss 
`selectFromCollectionView`
 using

> `self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)`

, then `UICollectionViewDataSource` method:

```
 collectionView (_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt
 indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

is called again, causing all the cells to be redrawn only to be thrown away as soon as the dismissal occurs. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Thanks.

Comment: is this impacting performance of application ?

Comment: Why does it matter if they're being redrawn unless it impacts performance? If you do any animations it should provably be done in willDisplayCell. I'm guessing you're presenting selectFromCollectionView from didSelectItemAtIndexPath?

Comment: The cells are displaying audio waveforms. When the user selects a cell the audio file corresponding to the waveform is sent back to the first view controller. When the cell is selected you can see the waveform get redrawn (it goes blank and comes back), it looks glitchy and I would like to avoid it if possible.